# Already 5 days am looking for updating Data access Table if table exist in using methode importation VBA Acces ;I Posted to have some idea please

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
Dim item As Variant

Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
diag.Filters.Clear
diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls, *.xlsx"

If diag.Show Then
    For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
        Me.txtFileName = item
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: My Codes Work very well just there create a new table on my database i want to add in existing tabe

Comment: I don't see any code for importing, just a `FileDialog` to select the file.